# JSON.parse get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token h"

Tags: javascript, json

I get the syntax error when I try to pass the following string:

```
JSON.parse("[{\"Date\": \"4/4/2016 4:15:19 PM\", \"Message\":\"<h3>New 
Message</h3> Generated at 4/4/2016 4:15:19 PM.<br/><br/>Heavy Responsive 
URL: <a href=\"https://performingarts.withgoogle.com/en_us\" ></a><br/><br/>
<img src=\"https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/06/bd/ac/06bdacc904c12abdce3381ba1404fd7e.jpg\" /> \"} ]");
```

I know that the error come from the link when I use double quote.

If I use single quote then no issue, but the data is getting from server side, I got no control over what going to pass in so I can only control on my side.

From what I read from the internet so far, I tried the following:

1. Use `JSON.stringify` first, then only use `JSON.parse`. I can parse
   with no issue but problem occur when I try to loop the data. Instead
   of looping it as JSON, the loop take the data as string and loop
   every single text.
2. Escape every double quote which I'm currently doing, but it's not
   working as shown above. But if I replace every double quote to
   literal, I'm afraid some of the message that suppose to be double
   quote will turn into literal as well, which will result in weird
   looking message.

Please advice what other alternative I have to solve this.

Comment: "Use JSON.stringify first, then only use JSON.parse" — That's the same as doing nothing at all.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Yes I realize that but I notice many people stated that it work for them for I just give it a shot. But it's not working for me.

Comment: You need to escape the backslash, too. When you do for `\"Date\"`, you make sure, that they survive Javascript and JSON sees those as string delimiters. If you also want JSON to ignore the quote, you need another backslash: `\\\"https...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have JSON embedded in a JavaScript string literal.

`"` and `\` are special characters in JSON and are also special characters in a JavaScript string literal.

`href=\"https:` escapes the `"` in the JavaScript string literal. It then becomes a `"` in the JSON. That causes an error.

When you want the `"` as data in the JSON you must:

- Escape the `"` for JavaScript (as you are doing already)
- Escape the `"` for JSON by adding a `\`.
- Escape the `\` for JavaScript

`href=\\\"https:`

Comment: Thanks! That's explain why I'm keep getting the syntax error eventhough i had escape the " for javascript.